what's the general approach to debug the undefined symbol and potential cause?
I've been developing a Python module in C++, but I got an ImportError with the message "undefined symbol" when trying to load the shared object .so file in Python.

undefined symbol: _ZN4llvm2cl18GenericOptionValue6anchorEv

I have three questions regarding how to further debug this kind of issue:
1, is this related to the linking library issues?
2, if yes, how to figure out which library is missing or linked incorrectly?
3, are the linked library necessary to be the shared object as well? I notice that when I compiled the code, I linked some static library, i.e., with the .a suffix files.

Unmangled, the symbol is llvm::cl::GenericOptionValue::anchor().

@DrewDormann sorry what does this mean? could you please detail it a bit?

Use a utility that can search files.  Search the files on your hard drive or development directory for the symbol.  If the symbol is not found, you need to reinstall the package.  If the symbol is found, then #include the header file or add the translation unit / library to your project.

Possible duplicate: What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?

Did you switch compilers or are you still using clang? I found this: https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-800.0.38/src/lib/Support/CommandLine.cpp.auto.html

@drescherjm i am using g++, not clang.

The error seems to have a dependency on llvm / clang.

I already linked the necessary (i think) llvm library. Is it because I missed some of them? @drescherjm

But all the lib I linked is static library. Are they required to be a shared obeject? .so.



is this related to the linking library issues?


Yes: the native library you are trying to import has not been built correctly.


if yes, how to figure out which library is missing or linked incorrectly?


The one you are trying to import.


are the linked library necessary to be the shared object as well?


I have no idea what you are asking here.
In order to successfully import a .so library into Python, that library must have been linked with all the libraries it depends on.

i am using g++, not clang
I already linked the necessary (i think) llvm library.

I suspect that your problem is either that you are linking against the wrong LLVM library(ies), or that:

you built LLVM libraries using Clang
you are trying to link these LLVM libraries into code built with g++.

Generally that doesn't work -- you need to use the same C++ compiler for both your code and all the libraries your code depends on.

To debug this, you need to find the symbols you depend on (_ZN4llvm2cl18GenericOptionValue6anchorEv here) and the symbols provided by the libraries you link against, e.g. nm -A libLLVM*.a | grep _ZN4llvm2cl18GenericOptionValue6anchorEv.
I expect the second command will produce no output for you (when using the LLVM  archive libraries you used to link your .so).
